# ngrx angular 14 selector keeps returning undefined

Tags: angular, ngrx

In my component outside the constructor I have:

```
userEmail = this.Authstate.pipe(select(selectUserInfo));
```

Inside my constructor I create my state with:

```
this.Authstate.dispatch(unencryptEmail({ email: this.userKey }));
```

In my ngOnInit() method I have:

```
this.userEmail.subscribe(console.log);
```

after running the above in state I have:
[image]

and from the console I have:
[image]

All good so far.
From state, I just want to get the email so for the moment, I change my subscribe in my ngOnInit method to be:

```
this.userEmail.subscribe(cc => console.log(cc?.LoggedInUser?.email));
```

State is still the same, but now in the console I get `undefined`.

Why can't I get the email?

*** Update ****

here's my selector code:

```
export const getAuthFeatureState = createFeatureSelector<AuthState>(authFeatureName);

export const selectUser = (state: AuthState) => state.profile;

export const selectIsAuthenticated = createSelector(
  getAuthFeatureState,
  (state: AuthState) => state.isLoggedIn
);

export const selectUserInfo = createSelector(
  getAuthFeatureState,
  (state: AuthState) => { return state.profile }
);
```

and my models:

```
export interface User {
  firstname: string,
  surname: string,
  email: string,
  phone: number,
  userId?: number,
  sex?: string,
  dateOfBirth?: Date,
  username: string,
  password?: string
}

export interface LoginUser {
  email: string,
  password: string
}

export interface LoggedInUser {
  LoggedInUser: User,
  token?: string
}
```

my reducer is:

```
export const authFeatureName = 'auth';

export interface AuthState {
  profile: LoggedInUser | null;
  isLoggedIn: boolean;
}

export const initialAuthState: AuthState = {
  profile: null,
  isLoggedIn: false,
};

const authReducerInternal = createReducer(
  initialAuthState,
 
  on(authActions.loginComplete, (state, { profile, isLoggedIn }) => {
    return {
      ...state,
      profile,
      isLoggedIn,
    };
  }),
  on(authActions.logout, (state, { }) => {
    return {
      ...state,
      profile: null,
      isLoggedIn: false,
    };
  }),
  on(authActions.unencryptEmailComplete, (state, { profile, isLoggedIn }) => {
    console.log("unencryptEmail complete action");
    return {
      ...state,
      profile,
      isLoggedIn,
    };
  })
);
```

My Effect is:

```
unencryptEmail$ = createEffect(
    () =>
      this.actions$.pipe(
        ofType(fromAuthActions.unencryptEmail),
        mergeMap((auth) => {
          return this.authService.doUnencryptEmail(auth.email)
            .pipe(map((data: LoggedInUser) => { return fromAuthActions.unencryptEmailComplete({ profile: data, isLoggedIn: false });  }))
        })
      ),
    { dispatch: true }
  );
```

in my reducer for unencrypEmail, If I put:

```
console.log("profile: " + profile);
```

then it ouputs `profile: [object object]`
if I then change it to:

```
console.log("profile: " + profile.LoggedInUser);
```

it outputs `profile: undefined`

Answer (score 0):

From your screenshot, `this.userEmail` is emitting this object:

[image]

You are are then executing the following code:

`this.userEmail.subscribe(cc => console.log(cc?.LoggedInUser?.email));`

Consider `cc` is the complete object from the console(as above), and you are are now trying to access its `LoggedInUser` property. This property does not exist, hence you get `undefined`.

You should use:

`this.userEmail.subscribe(cc => console.log(cc?.email));`

Comment: If I do `cc?.email` it errors with `email does not exist on type LoggedInUser`

Comment: Add your `AuthState` model to your question.

Comment: I've updated my question with my reducer and Effect

Comment: finally have it working. I needed to flatten the `LoggedInUser` interface i.e. `LoggedInUser: User` needed to be replaced with each of the items in user. Now it works.